# Maven Generate OpenAPI JSON for SpringBoot REST Controllers

Tags: spring-boot, maven, openapi

Is there a Maven plugin which can generate an openapi.json file at build time for my SpringBoot RestControllers?

If not a Maven plugin, is there another simple package to generate the file at build time?

I only want the openapi.json file, I don't want Swagger UIs auto-integrated, etc.

Comment: https://carlosvin.github.io/es/posts/creating-custom-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/).

I couldn't find a project which showed exactly my use-case (without all the swagger ui stuff), so I created an example project on GitHub for others to use as reference: [springdoc-maven-plugin-demo](https://github.com/kbaynes/springdoc-maven-plugin-demo)

Comment: This means we must start our whole SpringBoot web application in order to extract the API doc from it. :( I don't really like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring-doc](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) which support OpenAPI 3

Look at the [demos](https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/)

Comment: Is there a project in that repo that demonstrates building the openapi.json file via Maven? I couldn't find it.